# Showing live data from sensors on wordpress website

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

A client of mine has a website which has a scatter plot on it that is continuously updated through a live feed. My client has infrared sensors that pull this data. My client is able to parse this data into any kind of database. I need to know if there are any options that will allow me to do this. Something similar to what webtoolkit.eu does. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: ask your client how he does it

Comment: What features do you need that webtoolkit.eu wouldn't be able to provide? In addition, your question is a bit vague/broad. The way I'm interpreting it, you want to know how to set up an infrared sensor that publishes to a database, and how to create a web frontend that will show that data?

Comment: My client doesn't currently do that, but wants to be able to on the redesign. Also found out it is a infrasound sensor that sends data that is updated by the millisecond. On the wordpress website we would make it refresh the scatter plot every minute or so. I want to know is there any other way except webtoolkit.eu that this can be done. @MaximillianLaumeister

Comment: @KaushalKakadia Yes, you can use just about any web language to accomplish that. [Pick your poison.](http://codecondo.com/top-5-web-programming-languages-begin-learning-2014/)

Comment: Okay what are some other options that i have? @MaximillianLaumeister

Comment: @KaushalKakadia PHP, Node.js, Java, Ruby, Python, to name a few.

Comment: Okay last question, being a developer and understanding how to do this, typically how much would a project like this cost? @MaximillianLaumeister

Comment: @KaushalKakadia It depends on a lot of factors. I would probably ask someone who specializes in full stack web development, or someone who manages these kinds of projects.